# По поводу знаков в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Перерыла все правила написания прямой речи, но не смогла найти ответ на мой вопрос.

Как фраза оформлена правильно:

*— Я закончил, — он собрал тетради и убрал со стола.*

или:

*— Я закончил. — Он собрал тетради и убрал со стола.*

И если правилен второй вариант (или оба варианта), то как называется правило, которое регулирует пунктуацию в этом случае?

Всем, кто ответит, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **— Я закончил. — Он собрал тетради и убрал со стола.**

[Розенталь. § 49. Прямая речь перед словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)

2. Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют **собой отдельное предложение,** то они пишутся с прописной буквы:
   — Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Это тот случай, когда предложение после прямой речи **не является авторскими словами,** то есть оно не вводит прямую речь, не содержит слов со значением речи, мысли и т.д.