# Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> – Да, это заметно. – Павел Петрович начал, не торопясь, намазывать масло на хлеб. – Долго он у нас прогостит? ([Тургенев. Отцы и дети](http://rulibrary.ru/turgenev/otcy_i_deti/11))

Если здесь слова автора, связанные с прямой речью, то почему в конце первой части прямой речи стоит точка, а значит слова автора начинались бы с прописной даже если бы не были именем? Если здесь просто авторский текст, не связанный с прямой речью, но разбивающий ее пополам, то какими правилами такое регулируется?

Дополнение. Возможно, я нашел ответ на этот вопрос:

> Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы: — Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей. [(§ 49. Прямая речь перед словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154))

Однако последнее правило Розенталя приведено для прямой речи перед словами автора. Странно, что никто не применяет его для слов автора, разрывающих прямую речь. Все источники утверждают, что в этом случае слова автора пишутся со строчной.

Так что все равно хотелось бы услышать мнение других участников.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да, конечно, может.
Схема предложения Тургенева выглядит таким образом: **— П. — А. — П?**
(И неважно, что слова автора начинаются с имени. Можно написать их и так:
*Не торопясь, Павел Петрович начал намазывать масло на хлеб*.)

Похожие предложения:

*— Можешь поточнее описать, как он выглядел?

— Просто голубой листок. Вроде почтовой бумаги. — Он посмотрел на часы. — Через десять минут отчаливаю* (стр. 10; **— П. — А. — П.**).

*— Я частный детектив. — Страйк повысил голос, и лысоватый сменщик с интересом обернулся. — Вот моя визитка. Меня нанял брат Лулы Лэндри, мне необходимо поговорить…

— Так вы небось Рошель ищете? — Лысина склонилась к решетке. — Нету ее здесь. Ушла* (стр. 11; **— П? — А. — П.**).

*— Джон Бристоу? — Отхлебнув пива, полицейский уставился на ляжки одной из красоток; в его обручальном кольце отражались красные огоньки игрового автомата. — По-прежнему зацикливается на этой видеозаписи?* (стр. 12; **— П? — А. — П?**)
[**Р. Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки**](http://knizhnik.org/robert-gelbrejt/zov-kukushki/12)

Подобные особенности пунктуации уже рассматривались на сайте:
[По поводу знаков в прямой речи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429992/%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8/429993#429993);
[Ставится ли точка после прямой речи перед словами автора?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435615/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/436557#436557)

Мое мнение таково:
1) если предложение после прямой речи представляет собой слова автора, грамматически не связанные с прямой речью (это и есть т. н. самостоятельное предложение), то они [слова автора] начинаются с прописной буквы;
2) если авторское предложение не заканчивается "словами говорения" (т. е. двоеточия нет), то в его конце ставится точка. "Остаточная" прямая речь начинается с прописной.

**Дополнение**
Нашла предложение, в котором отражены многие нюансы пунктуации при прямой речи.

*— Ладно, ладно! — сказал хозяин, зевая. — Надо жить мирно и дружно. — Он погладил Каштанку и продолжал: — А ты, рыжик, не бойся... Это хорошая публика, не обидит. Постой, как же мы тебя звать будем? Без имени нельзя, брат* **(— П! — а. — П. — А: — П.)**.
А. П. Чехов. [Каштанка](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1146/p.3/index.html)

Comment: Благодарю за оценку моего ответа (правда, чтобы заслужить Ваше одобрение, надо постараться). Соответственно...

Comment: Ответ — блеск!!!

Comment: Аж зарделась! Спасибо, Александр.