# Когда слова автора после слов персонажа пишутся с прописной буквы?

Tags: прямая-речь, оформление-текста, диалог

Разные есть конструкции построения прямой речи (диалогов). Например:

***– Р, – а.***

***– Р! – а.***

***– Р? – а.***

Но в книгах я видела подобное оформление:

***– Такого не может быть. – Мужчина пошел к выходу.***

То есть, получается, это ***– Р. – А.*** Но в правилах такого нет. Тогда как понять, когда нужно ставить точку после слов персонажа и начинать слова автора с большой буквы?

Comment: Я задавал похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: Посмотрела, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*То есть, получается, это **– Р. – А.** Но в правилах такого нет.*

Есть такое в правилах. Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 49. Примечание](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)):

Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:
— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Схема этого предложения такова: **– Р! – А.**
Если предложение после прямой речи представляет собой слова автора, грамматически не связанные с прямой речью (то есть не содержат в себе так называемые "слова говорения": сказал, продолжил, вздохнул, переспросил, буркнул, пробормотал, усмехнулся, протянул...), то это и есть самостоятельное предложение. Оно начинается с прописной буквы.

*– Что врачи обещают? – спросила она.

– Мало что, в основном пугают. – **Я** попытался выглядеть беззаботным и стопроцентно уверенным в полнейшем и скорейшем восстановлении своей физической формы, но и совсем уж нагло врать тоже не хотелось. – Это нельзя, то нельзя, и нога какое-то время будет болеть, особенно на перемену погоды* (**– Р. – А. – Р.**).
*– А спина?

Ах, прозорливая ты моя! Про спину я малодушно умолчал, хотя по сравнению с этой проблемой больная нога казалась просто-таки фурункулом на фоне инфаркта.

– Ну, и спина, конечно, тоже. – **Мне** показалось, что я очень ловко увернулся от конкретного ответа* (**– Р. – А.**).
[**А. Маринина. Все не так**](http://knijky.ru/books/vse-ne-tak?page=3)

В одном из своих ответов я приводила в пример предложение, в котором отражены многие нюансы пунктуации при прямой речи.
*— Ладно, ладно! — сказал хозяин, зевая. — Надо жить мирно и дружно. — Он погладил Каштанку и продолжал: — А ты, рыжик, не бойся... Это хорошая публика, не обидит. Постой, как же мы тебя звать будем? Без имени нельзя, брат* (**— Р! — а. — Р. — А: — Р.**).
А. П. Чехов. Каштанка

Comment: Мне срочно понадобилась информация по этой теме, хотела задать вопрос на сайте, а тут Ваш ответ высветился!)  Девочка одна в сочинениях использует такие конструкции, а я совсем забыла, где искать объяснение прописной буквы. Спасибо и за ответ, и за ссылку!) И про Каштанку-то в тему...

Comment: И я Вас благодарю за оценку ответа. Мнение профессионалов всегда особенно ценно.