# Слова автора — прописная/строчная буква

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Верна ли такая схема? **"П". — А.**
Мой ответ: Нет.

Comment: Нет, — потому что есть пример из Правил?

Comment: Наоборот, я считаю, что эта схема неправильная. Её нет в правилах.

Comment: Никита, посмотрите ответы на вопросы: [Когда слова автора после слов персонажа пишутся с прописной буквы?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/442910/Когда-слова-автора-после-слов-персонажа-пишутся-с-прописной-буквы) и  [Может ли авторский текст... начинаться с прописной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/Может-ли-авторский-текст-разделяющий-прямую-речь-начинаться-с-прописной).

Comment: Всё равно непонятно

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9 Ответ с оценкой =Годится= не понятен?

Comment: Если в школе такая схема не рассматривается, учитель не говорит о ней и в учебнике нет, то, скорее всего, Ваш ответ будет верным. Но это не значит, что такого не может быть. Слова автора выражаются отдельным предложением, в котором нет глаголов "говорения". О таком типе оформления прямой речи нужно поговорить с учителем, показать примеры и правила из справочника, который дается по ссылке в этих ответах..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**«П», — а.

«П!» — а.

«П?» — а.

«П...» — а.**
Это [стандартные схемы](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192) оформления прямой речи — именно их изучают в школе, именно по ним, думаю, и производится тестирование.
Но такие решения нельзя признать **единственно** правильными. В большой литературе поро́й используются очень сложные пунктуационные конструкции. Пример из "Анны Карениной":

> — Получили наконец? — проговорил Степан Аркадьич, закладывая пальцем бумагу. — Ну-с, господа... — **И** присутствие началось. **(— П? — а. — П... — А.)**
>   «Если бы они знали, — думал он, с значительным видом склонив голову при слушании доклада, — каким виноватым мальчиком полчаса тому назад был их председатель!» — **И** глаза его смеялись при чтении доклада. **(«П, — а, — п!» — А.)**

Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).
Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение (то есть в них нет глаголов речи *сказал, закричал, воскликнул, прошептал, заметил, обронил, подумал* и т. д.), то они начинаются с прописной буквы.
Пунктуационное оформление, о котором идет речь, встречается не так часто, поэтому о нем не идет речь в учебниках русского языка, о нем не говорят в школе (в школе изучают не все правила правописания, ведь задача школы — заложить базовые сведения, а не подготовить профессионального корректора). Это правило приведено в пособии Д. Э. Розенталя «Пунктуация» (и было приведено в изданиях прежних лет), но это очень подробный справочник, в нем рассмотрены многие частные случаи, о которых не говорится в других справочных изданиях.

«Я же говорила». — Гордая мама подпёрла бока руками. **(«П». — А.)**
«День получки!» — Сторож похлопал себя по карману. **(«П!» — А.)**
«Спи, маленький, спи...» — Она поправила в коляске одеяло. **(«П...» — А.)**

Comment: Никита, надеюсь, что-то разъяснилось, улеглось?