# В данном примере после прямой речи слова автора начинаем с большой буквы?

Tags: прямая-речь

— А ты плавать умеешь? — Он склонил голову набок, рассматривая его с неприятной усмешкой.

Comment: Вот, как мне кажется, интересный пример: *— Но я, первосвященник иудейский, покуда жив, не дам на поругание веру и защищу народ! Ты слышишь, Пилат? – **И** тут Каифа грозно поднял руку: — Прислушайся, прокуратор!* (М. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита) Схема: **— П? — А: — П!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном - да, с прописной.

> [Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой
> отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=294080). Ср. с
> примером из справочника Д. Э. Розенталя «Современный русский язык.
> Пунктуация» (М., 2002):
>
> *— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.*
>
> Слова автора названы здесь отдельным предложением, т. к. в них **нет
> глагола речи** (*сказал, закричал, воскликнул* и т. д.). Правда,
> встречается такое оформление нечасто, поэтому многие справочники об
> этом правиле не вспоминают.

Этот вопрос уже обсуждался на сайте [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/442910/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B) и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Comment: Спасибо за максимально точный ответ. Долгое время не получалось найти конкретное указание на этот момент в правилах - везде почему-то  только употребление с глаголами речи. И хотя вроде знаю правильный ответ, все равно были сомнения.

Comment: Смотрите, что происходит при инверсии: — А ты плавать умеешь? — склонил он голову набок, рассматривая его с неприятной усмешкой. "Склонил" здесь в функции глагола речи. Или: — И вот ещё что... — Она нахмурилась. —  Не приходи сюда больше. /  — И вот ещё что... — нахмурилась она. —  Не приходи сюда больше. / Или:   — Эй!   — Он зло посмотрел исподлобья.  — Не балуй! / — Эй!   —  зло посмотрел он исподлобья.  — Не балуй! / Везде предложения полные, но перемена мест слагаемых превращает в глаголы речи отнюдь не речевые глаголы (под "и т. д." подразумеваются *хихикнуть, всхлипнуть, охнуть...*)

Comment: А если вместо вопросительного знака или точки в конце прямой речи стоит запятая, а слова автора звучат как отдельное предложение? Как тогда быть? Допустим ли такой вариант:           – Это было великолепно, — Незнакомый бард смахнул несуществующую слезу, пока довольная публика бросала монетки в раскрытый мешок на полу. – ...

Comment: То мы заменяем ошибочную запятую на "правильную" точку. *– Это было великолепно. — Незнакомый бард смахнул несуществующую слезу, пока довольная публика бросала монетки в раскрытый мешок на полу.* А вот тире далее невозможно (если следует текст собеседника): им дробится только диалог без слов автора. Если тире, то - с абзаца. Весь диалог на абзацах. Внакрут (с тире) только голые реплики.

Comment: Я недовольна своим пояснением: места мало, нужен отдельный вопрос. Однако сложные случаи мы прошли. Окликните linaglat@mail.ru, если будут новые вопросы, сюда я нечасто заглядываю.

Comment: С точкой ясно, а вот с тире не совсем, но все равно спасибо вам. Создам отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вот эта конструкция в конце ***– ... –*** меня смутила. Если дальше глаголет бард, то тире на месте. И далее всё он же, перемежаемый авторскими комментами?