# Слова автора после прямой речи. Верна ли пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

" — Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок, — она улыбнулась ему".

" — А, ну...давайте начнем урок. — Учитель отвернулся к доске"

Здравствуйте!  Вот скажите, прямая речь написана верно? И слова автора являются продолжением этой речи, или же эти два предложения достаточно автономны по отношению друг к другу?

Answer (score 2):

**Предложение 1**

Здесь два варианта оформления:

1) *— Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок. — **Она улыбнулась ему**.*

Слова автора представляют собой **отдельное предложение.**

*2) —* Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок,  — **улыбнулась ему он**а.

После прямой речи следуют слова автора.

**Розенталь** 2. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=157#pp157

Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:
— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Примеры:

― Ну и не надо. ― **Вика улыбнулась ему**. ― Я и сама слышала. [Анатолий Мельник. Авторитет (2000)]

Ну зачем же так? ― **вдруг улыбнулась ему Каменская.** ― Сейчас мы обо всем спокойно поговорим… [Вадим Громов. Компромат для олигарха (2000)

**Предложение 2**

— А, ну... давайте начнем урок. — Учитель отвернулся к доске.

В этом случае мы имеем **отдельное предложение**, порядок слов  только прямой. Глагол ***отвернуться*** вряд ли вообще подходит для передачи слов автора.

Comment: Подождите. А если б я написала "она" со строчной буквы, то уже было неверно?

Comment: Здесь дело в порядке слов, хотя Розенталь об этом не пишет. Глагол "улыбнуться" без проблем заменяет глагол "сказать". Но обратим внимание, что в корректно построенном предложении сразу ПОСЛЕ ПРЯМОЙ РЕЧИ ИДЕТ ГЛАГОЛ, то есть слова автора инверсированы. Если же подлежащее мы поставим на первое место (нормальный порядок слов), то это уже может выглядеть как отдельное предложение. Для примера возьмем самое простой вариант. "Подожди меня здесь", - попросила она.  Звучит нормально. А теперь изменим порядок слов. "Подожди меня здесь", -  она попросила. Такое предложение выглядит странно..

Comment: Поэтому "в функции слов, вводящих прямую речь, используются глаголы, обозначающие чувства говорящего, его ощущения, внутреннее состояние, а также глаголы, обозначающие мимику, жесты, движения". Но  те же глаголы могут входить в отдельное предложение,   если оно не начинается с глагола, а имеет другую структуру.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 48. Прямая речь после слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)):
…в функции слов, вводящих прямую речь, используются глаголы, обозначающие чувства говорящего, его ощущения, внутреннее состояние (*вспомнить, обрадоваться, огорчиться, удивиться, обидеться, возмутиться, ужаснуться и т. п.*), а также глаголы, обозначающие мимику, жесты, движения (***улыбнуться***, усмехнуться, рассмеяться, захохотать, вздохнуть, нахмуриться, подойти, подбежать, вскочить и т. п.). И те и другие глаголы допускают добавление к ним глаголов речи (обрадовался и сказал; удивился и спросил; улыбнулся и ответил; подбежал и воскликнул и т. д.), поэтому они воспринимаются как слова, вводящие прямую речь.

[Она улыбнулась ему:
— Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок.]

Я думаю, что здесь можно использовать ту же самую интерпретацию, только **наоборот** —  слова автора после прямой речи не являются отдельным предложением.

*— А теперь пройдёмте в вашу комнату, ваша милость, – **обворожительно улыбнулась ему хозяйка.** — Я сама прислужу вам* (М. Гилл. Ветер пыльных дорог).

*— Вроде не молодые уже, а вели себя как школьники, — **молодой человек смущённо улыбнулся*** (М. Серова. Дама с мертвой хваткой).

Многое зависит от ситуации: если предполагается, что кто-то говорит и улыбается в этот момент (и мы это знаем или чувствуем по контексту), то, конечно, лучше слова автора начинать со строчной буквы.

*— Спиртного в буфете нет, – **она улыбнулась ему и добавила:** – Вообще, важные вещи надо делать на трезвую голову – согласен?* (А. Симатов. Остров с зеленой травой)

**Дополнение** (после правки вопроса)

**— Начнем урок. — Учитель повернулся к доске, дети зашуршали тетрадями.**

*— Что вы еще спрашиваете?! — **з**лобно заревел профессор. — Все равно он уже пять раз у вас умер. Колите! Разве мыслимо! — **Л**ицо у него при этом стало как у вдохновенного разбойника* (М. Булгаков. Собачье сердце).

Примеры предложений и подробные разъяснения можно посмотреть здесь:
[Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: А можно сказать так.— Что вы еще спрашиваете?! — профессор злобно заревел.

Comment: Я понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду. Если глагол "зареветь" отнести ко второй части прямой речи (она-то ведь никуда не делась!), то пунктуация в предложении будет такой: _— Что вы еще спрашиваете?! — **Профессор злобно заревел:** — Все равно он уже пять раз у вас умер. Колите! Разве мыслимо!.._

Comment: Я не совсем об этом. Представьте, что продолжения нет, только первая прямая речь и слова автора. Можем ли мы оставить такую структуру для слов автора? Вы согласны, что глагол должен стоять после прямой речи.  Иначе говоря, отдельное предложение и слова автора могут иметь одинаковые глаголы, но они должны быть построены  по-разному.  А вот семантические отличия вариантов описывает в своем ответе М_Г.

Comment: Все правильно. _— Что вы еще спрашиваете?! — профессор злобно заревел._ Можно и так. До этого момента Ф. Ф. мычал, рычал, а потом ещё и засипел. Все это происходило в работе-диалоге... Вот оттуда же: _И насчёт «папаши» – это вы напрасно. Разве я просил мне операцию делать? – **человек возмущённо лаял**. – Хорошенькое дело!_ В своём ответе я ведь указала: Многое зависит от ситуации: если предполагается, что кто-то говорит и улыбается в этот момент (и мы это знаем или чувствуем по контексту), то, конечно, лучше слова автора начинать со строчной буквы.

Comment: Я думаю, что в большинстве случаев сказуемое в словах автора ставится сразу после прямой речи. У Булгакова,  может, особая ситуация, но и его в современных учебных текстах пытаются как-то поправить: Разве я просил мне операцию делать? - Человек возмущенно лаял - хорошенькое дело!

Answer (score 1):

> — Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок, — она улыбнулась ему.

В таком виде принять нельзя. Чтобы исправить, нужно понять, какую именно ситуацию описывает автор.

Вариант 1.  Она улыбнулась и сказала, или она сказала, улыбаясь. В таком случае слово *улыбнулась* вводит прямую речь. Но поставить его нужно непосредственно после прямой речи (см. ответ Sharon):

**— Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок, — улыбнулась она ему.**

Вариант 2.  Она сказала и улыбнулась (иная последовательность действий). В таком случае "Она улыбнулась ему" — отдельное предложение:

**— Поторопись, хулиган, скоро урок. — Она улыбнулась ему.**

> — А, ну...давайте начнем урок. — Учитель отвернулся к доске.

Здесь почти все верно, нужно только добавить пробел после многоточия. "Учитель отвернулся к доске" — отдельное предложение.

Дополнение. Согласен с замечанием Sharon: глагол *отвернуться* вряд ли подходит в данном контексте. Для описания обычной ситуации подходит глагол *повернулся*, а *отвернулся* подойдет, если, например, учитель обиделся на учеников и отвернулся к доске, смутился и отвернулся к доске и т.п. Или, например, учитель отвернулся к доске и потерял контроль над классом. Отворачиваются от кого-то. Отвернулся к доске = отвернулся от учеников и повернулся к доске.

> [ОТВЕРНУТЬСЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x), -нусь, -нёшься; св. 1. Повернуться в другую сторону, в сторону от кого-, чего-л. О. от окна, двери. О. от собеседника. О. в сторону от пламени, от пожарных. Недовольно о. от чьего-л. взгляда. О., чтобы не видеть. 2. только 3 л. Поворачиваясь по винтовой резьбе, ослабнуть или сняться; отвинтиться. Винт отвернулся. Гайка отвернулась легко, с трудом, без усилий. // Поворачиваясь, открыться. Кран отвернулся. 3. Отогнуться, загнуться. Рукав куртки отвернулся. Поля шляпы отвернулись от ветра. 4. от кого. Порвать отношения, перестать общаться с кем-л. О. от клеветника, недоброжелателя. Все отвернутся от кого-л., бросят его. <Отвёртываться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв. Отворачиваться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв. (1, 3-4 зн.).