# Правильность использования прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли использовать прямую речь таким образом:

- Они побежали в эту сторону. - Юрий услышал приближающихся офицеров.

Данные слова говорит не Юрий, а офицеры.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но... Авторские слова, представляющие отдельное предложение, идущие после прямой речи и не имеющие признака говорения, следует начинать с глагола:

— Они побежали в эту сторону, — услышал Юрий голоса приближающихся офицеров.

Отдельное предложение с прямым порядком слов, как у вас в вопросе, также имеет право быть (см. ответы на сайте: [Слова автора после прямой речи. Верна ли пунктуация?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447381/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)).