# Как правильно разделить на предложения отрывок текста?

Tags: прямая-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, разделить на предложения отрывок текста.

«Черт! — двигатель упорно не заводился. — Черт-черт-черт!» — Миша, кажется, уже битый час стоял на заправке.

Не могу никак определиться с границами предложений при прямой речи. Здесь их одно, два или четыре? Где можно найти правила?

Спасибо.

Comment: Наберите: «Предложение — это». Нужно знать определение, не правило.

Comment: У вас получилась прямая речь двигателя, а не Миши.

Comment: Про двигатель Вы хорошо сказали

Answer (score 2):

***— Черт!*** — Двигатель упорно не заводился. **— Черт-черт-черт!** — Миша, кажется, уже битый час стоял на заправке.

Здесь прямая речь персонажа сначала прерывается речью автора, а потом следует описание действия этого персонажа. В этом случае, как я думаю,  текст можно дать одним абзацем.

Деление на абзацы у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный Вами отрывок является ярким примером предложений с особенной структурой, в которых используются прямая речь. Более того, я ещё никогда не встречал примеров, где употребляются сразу две конструкции.
Начнём по порядку:

**Чёрт! — двигатель упорно не заводился. — Чёрт-чёрт-чёрт!**

Здесь мы видим прямую речь (человек, который бранится), **прерываемую словами автора**. В таком случае возможно некоторое количество конструкций, но данная является наиболее приоритетной (поищите в Интернете подобные случаи и разбираетесь самостоятельно), но на этом останавливаться  не буду. В общем, всё это сочетание может быть "разобрано" на три отдельных предложения:

**Чёрт!** & **Двигатель упорно не заводился.** & **Чёрт-чёрт-чёрт!**

Первое и третье являются прямой речью, необходимой для выражения чувств **героя**, а второе — замечанием **автора**, поясняющим причину столь сильного эмоционального напряжения.

А вот предложение **Миша, кажется, уже битый час стоял на заправке** также относится  к словам **автора**. Чтобы было понятно, проведу параллель:

**Миша, кажется, уже битый час *стоял* на заправке** в некоторой степени равносильно сочетанию **сказал Миша**, которое является для нас более привычным.

Таким образом, здесь можно разделить фрагмент на четыре предложения.

**P.s**: надеюсь, это не домашнее задание

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Нет, это не домашнее задание - хуже XD У меня есть задача посчитать среднее количество слов в предложении в нескольких текстах. Один текст, из которого я привела отрывок, изобилует предложениями с прямой речью. И вот тут у меня закрались сомнения, правомерно ли будет делить "по знакам препинания", то есть по количеству точек/восклицательных(вопросительных) знаков. Вот, например, на http://opencorpora.org/wiki предлагают для своих нужд правила деления на предложения, но я не очень поняла, на что они опираются.

Comment: Мне кажется моя проблема в том, что концептуально я не очень понимаю, является ли предложение с прямой речью по сути осложнённым предложением? Или это всё таки набор предложений, часть их которых являются словами автора, а часть собственно прямой речью.

Comment: На мой взгляд, осложнения и какие-то другие конструкции (как, например, прямая речь) всё же входят в одно предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу такие возможности разделения текста.

**1.** «Черт! — **Д**вигатель упорно не заводился. — Черт-черт-черт!» Миша, кажется, уже битый час стоял на заправке.
[Слова автора с заглавной; точка после кавычек не ставится.]

**2.** — Черт! — **Д**вигатель упорно не заводился. — Черт-черт-черт!
Миша, кажется, уже битый час стоял на заправке.
[Возможно дальнейшее продолжение текста.]

Вот примеры (М. А. Булгаков. Собачье сердце).

*«Неужели пролетарий? — подумал Шарик с удивлением... — Быть этого не может». Он поднял нос кверху, еще раз обнюхал шубу и уверенно подумал: «Нет, здесь пролетарием и не пахнет. Ученое слово, а бог его знает, что оно значит».*
[В кавычках прямая речь со словами автора и далее (отдельно) снова авторский текст.]

*— А-га, самец, — многозначительно молвил он, — ошейника нету, ну, вот и прекрасно, тебя-то мне и надо. Ступай за мной. — **О**н пощелкал пальцами. — Фить-фить!*
[**— П, — а, — п. — А. — П!** Вторые слова автора — с заглавной. Подробнее [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/441617#441617).]