# Слова автора (самостоятельное предложение) внутри прямой речи — оформление

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация

Обычно она оформляется таким образом:

*— Понимаешь, я бы тоже очень хотел этого. — Он встал и подошел к окну.*

А если такое предложение?

*— Понимаешь, — он встал и подошел к окну, — я бы тоже очень хотел этого.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй ответ

1. Римма, хорошие у вас примеры, я проголосовала за ваш ответ. Надо сказать, что **«Правила письма»**  в большом долгу перед этой темой – она очень неполно раскрыта  как точки зрения теории, так и практики. Вопросов по нестандартным вариантам задается много, а получить точный  ответ и сослаться на какой-то источник достаточно сложно.
2. Теперь **о приведенных примерах.** Все он выглядят очень естественно – все-таки писали мастера художественного слова.

*— Понимаешь, — она посмотрела на Марти глазами*, полными слез, — я столько раз просила Бога послать мне ребенка!

*— Хочу предложить вам, — тут женщина из-за пазухи вытащила несколько ярких и мокрых от снега журналов, — взять несколько журналов в пользу детей Германии. По полтиннику штука.*

*— Мой дорогой сэр, — на лице Вульфа изобразилось отвращение, — и вы тоже?*

3. А теперь добавлю **пример из Тургенева**, изменив оформление:

*— Да, это заметно, — Павел Петрович начал, не торопясь, намазывать масло на хлеб, —  долго он у нас прогостит?*

Здесь  такой вариант **вряд ли подойдет** – темп изложения событий  не тот. А почему же там подходил?  Можно быстро посмотреть на собеседника, можно изобразить какую-то мимику на лице. А у Булгкова авторские слова похожи на вставку, так что естественное сочетание слов разрывается (хочу предложить вам… взять).

И приходится делать вывод: **везде свои особенности**, позволяющие или не позволяющие использовать такое оформление.

4. Но вернемся **к нашему предложению** – теперь слово за автором. Теперь автор должен ориентироваться на свой собственный художественный вкус, а не просто заимствовать найденную  форму.

*Понимаешь, — он встал и подошел к окну, — я бы тоже очень хотел этого.*

Действие предполагает определенную затрату времени, так что в реальности **пауза** неизбежна. Но надо ли изображать эту паузу **в художественном пространстве** – вот в чем  вопрос!  Важно ли здесь подчеркнуть паузу? А это уже зависит от общего стиля произведения и от интуиции самого писателя.

Единственное, что не стоит делать, так это **точно копировать оформление**, взятое у других авторов.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ и за ваше собственное мнение на эту тему

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: Извините, *Sharon*, но я  не понимаю Вашей попытки переделать предложение Тургенева. В чем смысл? Ведь у него два *отдельных* предложения ("Да, это заметно" — повествовательное; "Долго он у нас прогостит?" — вопросительное), между которыми имеются слова автора. В нашем же вопросе конкретное разрываемое предложение только одно. И в нем у автора имеется имеется только запятая; никаких многоточий нет. И еще: никак не разумею, зачем же нужно занимать половину своего ответа переписыванием примеров из чужого?

Comment: Понимает, Римма, развитие наших знаний всегда проходит через определенные этапы: описание фактов, их сравнительный анализ и, наконец, заключительный вывод. Ваши примеры стали для меня таким описанием, поэтому мне было удобно расположить их рядом и вглядеться в них. Ну а тургеневский пример неоригинален (такое оформление встречается часто), его можно было заменить любым другим, более подходящим. И вот тогда  я делаю  вывод: каждый случай индивидуален, это художественный выбор автора,  это его вкус и интуиция.

Comment: Вы описываете модели и говорите автору: ваше оформление является правильным, так как такие примеры встречаются в литературе. У меня же  вывод другой: есть определенный смысл в  каждом варианте, есть свои тонкости и свои нюансы. Выбор правилен не сам по себе, а когда подходит для вашего конкретного текста. Неторопливость тургеневского героя отличается от взволнованной беседы  героев современного рассказа, и это обязательно надо учитывать.

Answer (score 3):

Объять все пунктуационные нюансы прямой речи, конечно же, правилами невозможно. Но можно рассуждать логически, опираясь на них и на примеры из добротной художественной литературы (которых предостаточно).

Вспомнился мой "пролетарский вопрос"; оттуда и классическое предложение ([Михаил Булгаков. Собачье сердце](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YC8kEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=-%20%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC,%20-%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,&source=bl&ots=k_SOabADSU&sig=ACfU3U1KGvJ0mIfAP_rNV1pQgsfCTrj9EQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN_8ufye3yAhW9SPEDHZvDDwsQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=-%20%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%2C%20-%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C&f=false)):

> — Хочу предложить вам, — **тут** женщина из-за пазухи вытащила  несколько
> ярких и мокрых от снега журналов, —  **взять**  несколько  журналов  в  пользу
> детей Германии. По полтиннику штука.

Вот оформление у любимого мною Рекса Стаута ("И быть подлецом"):
*— Мой дорогой сэр, — **на** лице Вульфа изобразилось отвращение, — **и** вы тоже?*

Вот предложение из книги Джанет Оак "Любовь никогда не перестает" (оно очень похоже на ваше):
***— Понимаешь, — она посмотрела на Марти глазами, полными слез, — я столько раз просила Бога послать мне ребенка!***

Так что если мы обрамляем *самостоятельные* слова автора запятой и тире, то и эти слова, и продолжение прямой речи пишутся со строчной буквы (то есть ваше оформление предложения является правильным):
***— Понимаешь, — он встал и подошел к окну, — я бы тоже очень хотел этого.***

Написание с многоточием перед словами автора тоже возможно. В этом случае авторское предложение — с заглавной буквы, в конце — точка, продолжение прямой речи — тоже с заглавной (Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки):

> — Ах, так? Ну погоди... — **И** он пошел из купе, но в две­рях еще оглянулся. — **Счас** ты у меня уедешь. — И вышел.

[Д. Розенталь. Русский язык на отлично. Упражнения и комментарии](https://books.google.ee/books?id=cZe8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F:%20%D0%AF%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=6XwGSjNFr3&sig=ACfU3U0bfDVG17HJKvDbNwFCsGq3cTJTzA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2yeTA1e3yAhUxS_EDHQWNDk8Q6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%3A%20%D0%AF%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false)

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ

Comment: И Вам поклон, *Marusya*. Вы задаете "умощипательные" вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

***— Понимаешь... — Он встал и подошел к окну. — Я бы тоже очень хотел этого.***

В любом случае здесь будет присутствовать пауза в речи, так как он ответил не сразу. Такую паузу удобно обозначить многоточием.

Исправление: Заглавная буква после многоточия, прописная в этом случае не пишется.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не нашла правил оформления прямой речи с предложениями, где описываются автором действия персонажа. Именно, когда авторские слова разрывают слова персонажа. В остальных случаях как оформить прямую речь я понимаю... 
В подобных случаях слово "Он" пишется с большой буквы, и перед ним ставится точка... ну или любой другой знак, кроме запятой.

Comment: Я не видела такого оформления в правилах. Розенталь различает текст от автора и действия говорящего лица, когда описывает построение абзацев  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161

Comment: Вот реальные примеры из правил и литературы.  — Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.
– Да, это заметно. – Павел Петрович начал, не торопясь, намазывать масло на хлеб. – Долго он у нас прогостит? 
— Что такое Базаров? — Аркадий усмехнулся. — Хотите, дядюшка, я вам скажу, что он, собственно, такое?

Comment: В начале предложения авторские слова оформляются по-разному, не только не в середине. Еще примеры:В один из таких дней прибежал Забродский: «Дмитрий Алексеевич, началось!..»   Пока откапывали увязшие в песке колёса, к нам подошёл милиционер:
— Кто такие?

Comment: Вот видите, в вашем примере "— Скорей, загорелась школа!..." "И он побежал..." - с большой буквы.

Comment: Другие варианты оформления прямой речи я знаю... Меня интересует только вариант, о котором я спрашивала первоначально... С авторскими словами без слов говорения внутри предложения.

Comment: Если вы хотите так написать, то напишите, но в правилах вы этого не найдете. Подобрать подходящий вариант в литературе тоже сложно, так то будьте ПЕРВОПРОХОДЦЕМ. Что это вам даст? Пожалуй, общий стиль письма — нестатичный, ускоренный. Что-то оригинальное в этом есть, если он, конечно,  вписывается в общее изложение сюжета.

Comment: @Marusya * Вот видите, в вашем примере*  - там точка (или вопросительный/восклицательный знак) в прямой речи на месте разрыва. Да и в этом-то случае заглавная неочевидна. А у вас фраза "понимаешь, я бы тоже..." - где точку ну никак не поставишь.

Comment: Уточню. *Да и в этом-то случае заглавная неочевидна* - тут для такого оформления нужно еще четкое понимание того, что речь автора используется именно как вставная конструкция. В ваших примера это совсем не очевидно.

Comment: Когда я впервые столкнулась с оформлением прямой речи без слов говорения, я начала искать информацию. Она оказалась противоречивой в различных источниках. И именно здесь нашла подобные вопросы с ответами, где участники форума сказали о подобном оформлении прямой речи - когда слова автора пишутся с большой буквы. Но ответ был дан не полностью, не были рассмотрены все примеры. Поэтому я задала отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: @Marusya *И именно здесь нашла подобные вопросы с ответами* Здесь? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614 Вы знаете, там очень неочевидное объяснение... Надо еще сто раз подумать и поискать хоть какой-то авторитетный источник.

Answer (score 1):

> А если такое предложение? — Понимаешь, — он встал и подошел к окну, —
> я бы тоже очень хотел этого.

Я бы оформил именно так. Именно так оформляется авторская речь внутри прямой в случае, если разрываемая прямая речь составляет одно предложение.
При этом ни у Розенталя, ни у Лопатина нет каких-то оговорок на "самостоятельность" авторской речи.
Тут, конечно, случай не совсем типичный, в словах автора нет связи с прямой речью: ни характерных "речевых"  глаголов (сказал, подумал, решил, раздался и проч.), ни каких-то существительных, используемых в качестве связующих (типа "это его мысли" или "его любимое выражение"). Но я не вижу в этом причины отказываться от общих рекомендаций.

Comment: Наверное, по другому и не напишешь. Рекомендация, где первая часть слов персонажа должна оканчиваться точкой, а далее авторские слова начинаться с большой буквы, вступает в противоречие получается... Ведь немного странно будет выглядеть текст с такими знаками: "Понимаешь, — Он встал и подошел к окну, — я бы тоже очень хотел этого".

Comment: @Marusya *первая часть слов персонажа должна оканчиваться точкой вступает в противоречие* -  Ээээ... Пролстите, а где вы подобную рекомендацию нашли? Тем более, что у вас не точка, а запятая на месте разрыва. Поэтому тем более странно выглядит заглавная, в этих случаях вообще никаких точек и **лишних** заглавных быть не должно.  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm - посмотрите §121 "Авторские слова внутри прямой речи".

Comment: Так в этом и состоит мой вопрос. В приведенном примере у меня не утверждение, я всего лишь хочу разобраться с пунктуацией, именно при отсутствии слов говорения.

Comment: Конечно, странно, если после запятой заглавная буква...

Comment: @Marusya * Так в этом и состоит мой вопрос.*  - так я на него и ответил. Давайте откатим чуть назад, не возражаете? Можете указать на источник "рекомендации"  "первая часть слов персонажа должна оканчиваться точкой, а далее авторские слова начинаться с большой буквы"? Или хотя бы пример такого оформления. Примеры от Sharon заведомо не годятся.  Там такое оформление потому, что три разных фразы, действия слов автора вообще никак не связано с прямой речью.

Comment: Да, можно. https://writercenter.ru/blog/useful-stuff/otdelnoe-predlozhenie-v-dialogah.html

Comment: @Marusya Ну видите ли, источник сей никак не назовешь авторитетным. И не то беда, что автор никому не известен, а в том, что он вводит свою, непонятную терминологии. И на этой же терминологии строит свое объяснение подобных примеров. И критикует Розенталя, опять-таки не разобравшись. Чтобы далеко не ходить: пример из Гоголя (с двоеточием) это вообще другой случай, там авторская речь относится только к одной, второй, части речи героя.

Comment: Вам, полагаю, следовало изначально указать, в вопросе, что вы используете идеи и терминологию такого-то блогера. В целом же не могу сказать, что сформулированная автором рекомендация рекомендация.  Он из своих примеров - не спорю многочисленных - выводит правило, не указывая область и границы его применения. Я чуть позже добавлю в текст ответа свои мысли по поводу именно этой позиции. В целом я, думаю, понял, в чем он грешит против истины, но не хочу писать экспромтом.

Comment: Неважно, что автор статьи не столь известный. Примеры из классической и современной литературы дают понять, что не все так однозначно в прямой речи... В любом случае, благодарю вас за ваше мнение. Именно за другим мнением я сюда и обращаюсь.